# Is valueForKey is case insensitive for Keys?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is valueForKey is case insensitive for Keys?

All the following piece of code give me same result:

```
[myObject valueForKey:@"test"];
[myObject valueForKey:@"Test"];
[myObject valueForKey:@"tEst"];
[myObject valueForKey:@"teSt"];
[myObject valueForKey:@"test"];
[myObject valueForKey:@"tesT"];
[myObject valueForKey:@"TEST"];
```

my key name inside myObject is test.

Comment: By case insensitive I meant that in what ever case I pass the key valueForKey is returning me the correct results. In my understanding, keys should be unique & case sensitive... Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at keyvaluecoding:

The following link is no longer valid.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA